# Modify the text content of HTML tags in a big HTML file using BeautifuSoap with Python

Tags: python, html, string, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to replace all the text content of the HTML tags in a big HTML file with another translated text, I am currently using Beautiful Soap with Python to this but there is a problem with Beautiful Soap traversing the DOM tree of the HTML file.

Here is what I tried:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from englisttohindi.englisttohindi import EngtoHindi

readFile = "./index.html"
writeFile = "./index1.html"


def translate_page(readFile, writeFile):
    
    f = open(readFile, 'r+')
    f1 = open(writeFile, 'r+')


    soup = bs(f.read(), 'html.parser')
    
    for tag in soup.find_all():
    
        if(hasattr(tag, "string") and tag.string != None and tag.string != '\n' and tag.name != "style" and tag.name != "script"):
            hindi = EngtoHindi(message=tag.get_text(strip=True)).convert
            tag.string.replace_with(hindi)
            f1.write(f'{tag}')
            
            
        else:
            f1.write(f'{tag}')
           
    f.close()
    f1.close()
       
translate_page(readFile, writeFile)
```

The output is the same as the input with no changes in the text content except for few tags which have been successfully translated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import the necessary libraries - BeautifulSoup and os
2. Set the file path of the HTML file
3. Open the HTML file and parse it using BeautifulSoup
4. Find the HTML tags that need to be modified using the find_all() method
5. Loop through the found tags and modify the content using the .string or .text attributes
6. Save the modified HTML file back to the original file path

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

# set file path
file_path = "path/to/your/html/file.html"

# open and parse html file
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    html = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# find tags to modify
tags_to_modify = soup.find_all("tag_name")

for tag in tags_to_modify:
    # modify tag content
    tag.string = "new_content"

# save modified html file
with open(file_path, "w") as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```